# How to reuse a Button action

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am trying to reuse the action of this button, without recalling the command all over again, the thing is that, after the button executes the first "if" statement "y == 1".
Now, instead of having access to the second "if" statement "y == 2" (That is, assume the program starts now, if I enter 1 in the entry box and the button is clicked, the program should print "Yes!", then if I enter 2 again in the entry box and the button is clicked, the program should print "Yes!Yes!", but instead it starts the "def action()" all over again)

I want it to run like the second code if I use a console

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()

def action():
    y = x.get()
    if y == 1:
        print("Yes!")
        if y == 2:
            print("Yes!Yes!")
        elif y == 3:
            print("Yes!Yes!Yes!")
    else:
        print("No")

x = IntVar()
e1 = Entry(win, textvariable = x).grid()
b1 = Button(win, text = "Button", command = action).grid()
win.mainloop()
```

The second code

```
y = eval(input("Enter a value: "))
if y == 1:
    print("Yes")
    y = eval(input("Enter a value: "))
    if y == 2:
        print("Yes!Yes!")
    elif y == 3:
        print("Yes!Yes!Yes!")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

put

```
y = x.get()
clicked = False
```

after

```
b1 = Button(win, text = "Button", command = action).grid()
```

Now,

```
def action():
    if y == 2 and clicked == True:
        print("Yes!Yes!")
    if y == 3 and clicked == True:
        print("Yes!Yes!Yes!")
    if y == 1 and clicked == False:
        print("Yes!")
        clicked = True
```

If I understood your question well, this might pop the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

> if I enter 1 in the entry box and the button is clicked, the program
> should print "Yes!", then if I enter 2 again in the entry box and the
> button is clicked, the program should print "Yes!Yes!", and so on.

Walrus to rescued.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()

def action():
   # y = x.get()
    if (y := x.get()) == 1:
        print("Yes!")
    elif y == 2:
        txt= 'Yes!'
        print(txt*2)
    elif y == 3:
        txt = 'Yes!'
        print(txt*3)
    else:
        print("No")

x = IntVar()
e1 = Entry(win, textvariable = x).grid()
b1 = Button(win, text = "Button", command = action).grid()
win.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
Yes!
Yes!Yes!
Yes!Yes!Yes!
No
```